# How to split a list with a fixed number of items in each sublist

Tags: python, list, count, duplicates

I have a list say:

```
my_list=[1,2,3,1,5,6,7,5,9,9]
```

I want to create sub-lists with each sub-list containing 4 items.The number of sub-lists would depend on the length of the original list (my_list) but each should have maximum 4 items.
i.e.

```
a1=[1,2,3,1]
a2=[5,6,7,5]
a3=[9,9]
```

so i did this :

```
n=4
final = [my_list[i * n:(i + 1) * n] for i in range((len(my_list) + n - 1) // n )] 
print (final)
```

Now i want to check if , then how many elements are getting repeated in a sub-list and append that to a new list, say q.For that i did this:
i tried using :

```
q=[]    
for i in range(len(final)):
                  for a in final[i]:
                      k=final[i].count(a)
                      q.append(k)
    print(q)
```

But this is giving me a very long list like this:

```
[2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```

however all i want is,the total number of times a number is repeated in the sub-list,something like this :

```
l=[3] #for the whole my_list
```

or

```
l=[[1],[1],[1]] #specifying for every sub-list
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you can get number of repeated elements on this way - compare sublists and sets created from them:

```
my_list=[1,2,3,1,5,6,7,5,9,9]
n=4
final = [my_list[i * n:(i + 1) * n] for i in range((len(my_list) + n - 1) // n )] 
print (final)

total=0
for el in final:
    s=list(set(el))
    total+=len(el)-len(s)

print(total)
```

Answer (score 2):

This will give you a count sublist for each original sublist you have

```
q=[]    
for i in range(len(final)):
    sub_list_q = []
    for a in final[i]:
        k=final[i].count(a)
        for _ in range(k): # Remove duplicates
            final[i].remove(a)
        if k-1 > 0:
            sub_list_q.append(k-1) # Only append if it's a duplicate
    q.append(sub_list_q)
print(q)
```

Comment: this does works out but it is still giving me repetition for each element in the sublist, so for 4 elements in the sublist it gives me something like this [2, 1, 1, 2] however i just want 1 item from the list i.e [1] as this indicates that there is an item in the sublist and it is getting repeated.

Comment: think you mean `sub_list_1.append(k)` but either way this will count 1 twice. We need to remove the other instances of a counted value and only append values that are greater than 1

Answer (score 0):

First off you can define your `final` list comprehension in a more concise and clear way (imo):

```
my_list=[1,2,3,1,5,6,7,5,9,9]

final = [my_list[n: n+4] for n in range(0, len(my_list), 4)]
```

Then, to print out the number of duplicates, you can actually operate on the original list, which will be a simpler operation than processing the 2d array:

```
total = len(my_list) - len(set(my_list))
```